# Howto share Typescript libraries between Loopback (NodeJS) and Angular apps in monorepo

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, loopback4, nrwl-nx

I have a monorepo (using nx as manager), which contains five Angular apps, and one Loopback 4 (NodeJS, TS) app.  I also have several Angular libraries which are shared as expected, and using `@angular-architects/ddd` to architect the types of libraries and dependencies/constraints between them.

Folder structure:

```
apps
    angular1
    angular2 (and 3,4,5)
    loopback
libs
    angular-shared
    ts-shared
```

I would now like to create a shared library `ts-shared` of simple typescript functions (without any dependencies to Angular, Loopback) - for instance financial calculations as PV, FV, INT, etc., that I would like to be shared by both Angular as well as Loopback code.

For example:

in ts-shared lib:

```
export const square = (n:number):number => n*n;
```

and then consumed in Angular:

```
import { square } from '/path/to/lib' ;

const res = square(5);
```

This all works fine.

However when I do the same in my Loopback code, I am faced with IDE/build issues (shortened for readability) similar to

```
error TS6059: File '/xxx/libs/util-core/src/lib/services/algorithm.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/xxx/apps/loopback-api/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

My Loopback tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@loopback/build/config/tsconfig.common.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
  "references": [],
  "files" : []
}
```

I presume its because (as it states) the library is not under the source code directory of the Loopback app - which I realise and understand - it's by design this way.

I have tried various combinations of include, files and references, but no luck.  I have googled quite a bit but have not found anything useful or relevant.

Does anyone have any suggestions please? Or perhaps a working repo of something similar that I can have a look at?

At this point I am happy with nx, and am hoping not to need workspaces, lerna, or other new technologies unless I have no alternative.

Comment: I know i said I didn't want to make dramatic changes, but am seriously considering ditching Loopback in favour of NestJS. The documentation at least seems really comprehensive (as does the actual feature set), and it seems to be inspired by Angular - so the look and feel is very familiar.  And it plays really nicely together with NX / monorepos...  Watch this space